# R can not be resolved

Tags: java, android

Every projects which is preexisted in workspace now gives problem of `R can not be resolved` so what i have to do. i have done lot effort but error is still there. Here is screen shot of that. [image] (Click on image to enlarge)

Comment: Have you looked at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error?rq=1) ?

Comment: Did you try to modify `R.java` file?

Comment: search R and then delete R?

Comment: @VimalBera no i have not try to modify it.

Comment: try other posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error?rq=1

Comment: Try 2 things. Perform a "clean" (under project -> clean). If it doesn't work, try to delete your project and re-import it.

Comment: @sqlab i have only delete R file from Gen folder as per answer by stack overflow in likely question previously. but it doesn't effect.

Comment: Hii.. Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @NehaPatel Why have you delete R.java file??? ?

Comment: i have done all the solutions which is given here but it doesn't work for me. thats why i have post my question here.

Comment: i have downloaded fresh new copy of adt bundle & i have started to create new project from that. but still there is same error.

Comment: I Think Actual Problem is in R file. I mean **it is not created in Gen folder when i create new project**. & in every projects which is already in my workspace **doesn't show R file in Gen Floder.**

Comment: ** Thank You All**. Error is solved now. i am referencing java doc. on my network's path. so i should refeence it on local host only.

Answer (score 1):

Android generates the special R.java file from all your xml resource files. If it doesn't get generated, either the build process or IDE is not correctly configured or there's a problem in one or more of the xml files. Check your logs for any hints.

Comment: i have downloaded fresh new copy of adt bundle & i have started to create new project from that. but still there is same error.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reason when `R can not be resolved` error comes.

First try to clean your Project from **Project--> Clean**

Second Delete gen Folder and then restart your eclipe from **File--> Restart**

Then go to **Windows --> Preferences --> Android --> and Select the API** you want.

and again clean the Project and If need Restart your eclipse.

Hope this Help..

Comment: i have downloaded fresh new copy of adt bundle & i have started to create new project from that. but still there is same error.

Comment: and i have also done all the above solutions which is given here.

Comment: Have you set Path of SDK from preferences?